# Eliminar carácter no validos de una url (php)

Tags: php

Busco como de eliminar los `"\"` de esta url

`"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c523219\/u213324802\/video\/l_7325c886.jpg"`

usando php.

Lo intento de esta manera:

```
<?php
$url = 'https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c523219\/u213324802\/video\/l_7325c886.jpg';
urldecode($url);
echo $url;
?>
```

Igual no funciona .
Busco alguna idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que estás buscando es **[`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)**, la cual te permite reemplazar todas las ocurrencias de una cadena en un string de PHP.

En el primer parámetro le indicaremos la cadena a buscar dentro del `string`, en el segundo parámetro la cadena por la cual va a ser reemplazada, que en este caso va a ser vacío y en el tercer parámetro el `string` en el cual queremos hacer el reemplazo.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $string = "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c523219\/u213324802\/video\/l_7325c886.jpg";
    $stringModificado = str_replace("\\", "", $string);

    echo $stringModificado;
```

Resultado:

```
https://pp.userapi.com/c523219/u213324802/video/l_7325c886.jpg
```

**Nota**: Si te fijas, utilizo doble `\\` ya que la barra invertida se utiliza para escapar caracteres especiales y, por tanto, si queremos utilizar esa barra invertida dentro de un `string` deberemos escaparla mediante otra barra invertida.

Comment: Excelente me quedo claro gracias

Answer (score 3):

Podrías aplicar primero [`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`](http://php.net/manual/es/filter.filters.sanitize.php), esta función elimina caracteres ilegales en tu `url`, para así lograr mayor seguridad.

> **`FILTER_SANITIZE_URL`:** Elimina todos los caracteres excepto **letras**, **dígitos** y **$ - _ .  + ! * ' ( ) , { } |   \  ^ ~ [ ] ` < > # % " ; / ? : @ & = .**

El segundo paso sería aplicarle la función [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php), ya mencionado, ya que la barra invertida no es ilegal en una `url`.

`$string = str_replace('\\', '', $string);`

En particular, si quiere coincidir una barra invertida, escriba `\\`.
[Manual secuencias de escape](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php).

*Un posible ejemplo:*

```
//Tu url, con caracteres ilegales (����).
$string = "https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c52����3219\/u213324802\/video\/l_7325c886.jpg";
//Aplicamos el filtro.
$string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
//Sustituimos la barra invertida (\) por un espacio en blanco.
$string = str_replace('\\', '', $string);
//Resultado
echo $string;
```

*Resultado*: `https://pp.userapi.com/c523219/u213324802/video/l_7325c886.jpg`

Comment: Gracias este punto es bastante interesante de aprender